# auto play duplicate audio on IE11 (vimeo)

Tags: internet-explorer, vimeo-player

**Vimeo auto play duplicate audio on IE 11**
I have added embedded vimeo video in colorbox with parameter autoplay=1. when open video its create duplicate audio only on IE 11, its work fine on all browser

Comment: Can you link to the site with the problem? Or provide a code sample that replicates the issue?